# Excel auto populate based on rules of groups of cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a formula to fill a cell with an "X" if 3 conditions are met. What I need is cell AU to be auto-populated with an "X" if cells AF through AK have at least 3 "X" in total, and cells AL through AR have at least 1 "X" in them and if cell AS is filled with an "X". Then cell AW would be the same formula except the required number of "X" would double, so AF through AK would need 6, and so on.

[image: spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0):

Test multiple conditions with `AND`. Let’s assume that the data starts in row 4. For cell `AU4`, the three conditions you need to test are:

1. `COUNTIF($AF4:$AK4, "X") ≥ 3`
2. `COUNTIF($AL4:$AR4, "X") ≥ 1`, and
3. `$AS4 = "X"`

Use `IF` and `AND` to set `AU4` to "X" if all the conditions are TRUE, otherwise `AU4` is "". This is the formula for cell `AU4`:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($AF4:$AK4,"X")≥3,COUNTIF($AL4:$AR4,"X")≥1,$AS4="X"),"X","")
```

The formula for cell `AW4` tests for the additional "X" values in the cells:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($AF4:$AK4,"X")≥6,COUNTIF($AL4:$AR4,"X")≥2,$AS4="X"),"X","")
```

Here are some test samples.

[image: spreadsheet test samples]